# Variable passing IS NOT working - value Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, variables, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I have a serious problem that i have been trying to debug for a few days already. 
I have a script that gets users current latitude and longitude, and then stores them in variables. however, when i try to use these variables outside this function and in the //init map zone, the map is just not showing up. by alerting out the variables i can see that outside the position function variables are set to "Undefined". here is my code:

```
//main function here
function initialize() {
var lat;
var lon;

//check if user has geo feature
if(navigator.geolocation){

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
//get position
function(position){
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    },
// if there was an error
function(error){
    alert('ouch');
});
}
//case the users browser doesn't support geolocations
else {
alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocations, please consider downloading Google Chrome");
}
//init map
var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

}
```

Thanks for any help, Ariel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>That is because you declare your variables within the function. The variables gets private to the `initialize` function and can only be accessed from within it. If you need to be able to access your variables outside of the initialize function, then move the variable declaration out of the function.</strike>

```
var lat;
var lon;
function initialize() {
...
```

Have a look at this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Variable_scope) about variable scope in JavaScript.

**UPDATE**

Looking through the code again I realize that the problem isn't variable scope, got confused by the indentation. I'm not familiar with the Geolocation API but I believe that the problem might be that the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous, as it will have to wait for the user to allow the website to get the position of the device. Therefor `myOptions` will have been assigned before the actual position have been retrieved - thus `lat` & `lng` are still undefined when `myOptions` is assigned.

Try this instead:

```
//main function here
function initialize() {
var lat, lon, map, myOptions;

//check if user has geo feature
if(navigator.geolocation){

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
//get position
function(position){
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;

    //init map
    myOptions = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
       zoom: 16,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
},
// if there was an error
function(error){
    alert('ouch');
});
}
//case the users browser doesn't support geolocations
else {
alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocations, please consider downloading Google Chrome");
}
}
```

Comment: That is not my problem, my problem is that in "center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)," the variables lat and lon apparently have no valute at all.

Comment: @arielschon12 What do you get if you `console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);` within that function?

Answer (score 0):

More of a correction on the other answer.  The issue of *scope* is not relevant.  As defined in the original code `lat` and `lon` are in scope in the context to which the question author is using `alert`.

Here's a runnable example that proves it.

```
function getPos( f ) {
    var position = new Object();
    position.coords = new Object();
    position.coords.latitude = 5;
    position.coords.longitude = 10;
    f( position );          
}


function initialize() {
    var lat;
    var lon;
    getPos(

        function(position){
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lon = position.coords.longitude;
            }

            );

       alert( lat + " " + lon );

}


initialize(); //expected 5 & 10
```

Anyways, this doesn't seem to be a pure JS issue.  This seems to be an issue with whatever google api you are using.  This question should have been tagged with such, as I have no knowledge of this API or whether you're calling it wrong or not.